# Can Excel userforms create a combobox when the form is running and having a trigger for that new combobox?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a + and - button to add and remove combo-boxes in a user form, the problem i'm having is getting code to trigger when those new boxes are changed. I was wondering if its possible to have triggers for items that don't exist until i press the + button in the form?

I have tried to add triggers with the name that the box will have but it doesn't activate.

This is the code i use to create the new boxes and set them up.

```
Private Sub AddRow_Click()
SearchCount = SearchCount + 1
UserForm1.Height = UserForm1.Height + 30
UserForm1.ListBox1.Top = UserForm1.ListBox1.Top + 30
UserForm1.TextBox4.Top = UserForm1.TextBox4.Top + 30
UserForm1.TextBox5.Top = UserForm1.TextBox5.Top + 30
UserForm1.TextBox6.Top = UserForm1.TextBox6.Top + 30
UserForm1.ApplyButton.Top = UserForm1.ApplyButton.Top + 30
UserForm1.ResetButton.Top = UserForm1.ResetButton.Top + 30
UserForm1.AddRow.Top = UserForm1.AddRow.Top + 30
UserForm1.RemoveRow.Top = UserForm1.RemoveRow.Top + 30

Set cmbo1 = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Combobox.1", "ColumnPicker" & SearchCount)
obj1.Add cmbo1, cmbo1.Name
Set cmbo2 = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Combobox.1", "Operator" & SearchCount)
obj2.Add cmbo2, cmbo2.Name
Set txt3 = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", "Condition" & SearchCount)
obj3.Add txt3, txt3.Name
Set cmbo4 = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Combobox.1", "Logic" & SearchCount)
obj4.Add cmbo4, cmbo4.Name

Count = Sheets("Analyzer").ListObjects("Analyzer").ListColumns.Count - 1
ReDim ColumnArr(Count)
With cmbo1
    .Top = 50 + (30 * (SearchCount - 1))
    .Left = 18
    .Height = 24
    .Width = 192
    For i = 0 To Count
        ColumnArr(i) = Sheets("Analyzer").Cells(3, i + 1).Value
    Next i
    For j = 0 To Count
        .AddItem (ColumnArr(j))
    Next j
End With
With cmbo2
    .Top = 50 + (30 * (SearchCount - 1))
    .Left = 216
    .Height = 24
    .Width = 180
    .AddItem ("Starts With")
    .AddItem ("Contains")
    .AddItem ("=  Equals")
    .AddItem ("!= Does Not Equal")
    .AddItem (">  Greater Than")
    .AddItem (">= Greater Than Or Equals")
    .AddItem ("<  Less Than")
    .AddItem ("<= Less Than Or Equals")
    .Text = "Contains"
End With
With txt3
    .Top = 50 + (30 * (SearchCount - 1))
    .Left = 402
    .Height = 24
    .Width = 420
End With
With cmbo4
    .Top = 50 + (30 * (SearchCount - 2))
    .Left = 828
    .Height = 24
    .Width = 60
    .AddItem ("And")
    .AddItem ("Or")
    .Text = "And"
End With
End Sub
```

[This is the layout of the userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eeym6.png)

[This is the userform after adding new boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBuwb.png)

If there isn't a way to do it i will just have to create the boxes first and change there visibility with code, that way i can link the triggers first.

Comment: i think you're looking for `combobox_change`, using a modeless userform; you could also dynamically add controls to a userform with code, which is your + button you were talking about

Comment: @Cyril Thanks for the tip with using modeless userforms although i still cant get the combobox_change to trigger when the new combobox is changed.

Comment: Create the controls manually, attach the event code to them and then programmatically move them to a location outside of the visible area of the form until you need them, and then programatically move them back into view. Much simpler

Comment: You could create a class module or UDF for the ComboBox to look if its been creted or not, but honestly the comment by @HarassedDad is going to be the easiest solution.

Comment: @HarassedDad That's what my backup solution was and i do agree that it is much simpler. I will begin changing the for but i am still curious to see if it is possible. thanks guys.